# Make Two Buttons Have Equal Width

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have the following:

```
<DockPanel Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Button Content="Add" x:Name="bAdd" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
    <Button Content="Remove" x:Name="bRemove" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
</DockPanel>
```

Can someone suggest me how to make both the buttons have equal width without setting the `Width` property of the buttons manually?

Comment: Don't think you can set the width without setting the width.

Comment: Why you dont want to use the Width propety? is there an issue with it?

Comment: The window can be resized by the user and I want the buttons to resize too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF buttons same/recommended width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658511/wpf-buttons-same-recommended-width)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you absolutely don't want to set the `Width` propety, you can just use a `Grid` :

```
<Grid Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Add" x:Name="bAdd" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Remove" x:Name="bRemove" />
</Grid>
```

They will both have the same `Width` this way

Comment: Was just about to hit "Post answer" when I reloaded and saw this - this is by far the easiest approach for dynamic, yet equal-width controls.

Comment: I second this. What I normally do is this.

Comment: Classic stackoverflow situation: about to hit post answer, somebody just did :) On a more related note, the * value for width & height is one of those things which just make WPF awesome. I can't use Winforms  anymore now!

Answer (score 7):

```
<UniformGrid Columns="2">
 <Button Content="Ok" Grid.Column="0"/>
 <Button Content="Cancel" Grid.Column="1"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the @Amir's answer you can control the numbers of buttons dynamically by binding Visbility.

```
<UniformGrid Rows="1">
 <Button Content="Ok" Visiblity="{Binding IsShowOkayButton, Converter={...}"/>
 <Button Content="Cancel" Visiblity="{Binding IsShowCancelButton, Converter={...}}"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

Use with enumeration:
(Assuming that ConfirmType and IsShowCancelButton in the same ViewModel)

```
public enum ConfirmType { Confirm, ConfirmOrCancel }

public ConfirmType ConfirmType { get => _ConfirmType; 
            set {
                switch (_ConfirmType)
                {
                    case ConfirmType.Confirm:
                        IsShowCancelButton = false;
                        break;
                    case ConfirmType.ConfirmOrCancel:
                        IsShowCancelButton = true;
                        break;
                }
                // Your RaisePropertyChanged code here
            }
        }
```