# How to specify units in Dialog Units in WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, user-experience

i'm trying to figure out how to layout a simple dialog in WPF using the proper dialog units (DLUs).

i've come up with a simple<sup>[r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395195/wpf-how-to-specify-units-in-dialog-units)</sup> example, that cuts straight to the problem:

[image]

You can check the [Windows UX Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511279.aspx#sizingspacing) to see where these measurements come from.
The short version is:

- dlu = *dialog unit*
- dlu is based on the font size (*items change with user's font size*)
- a *horizontal* dlu is different from a *vertical* dlu (*dlu's are not square*)

This comes from the definition of a dialog unit: *the average character is 8dlus high by 4dlus wide*.

**Georgia 14pt:**

[image]

If you use a smaller font (i.e. 8pt Tahoma verses 14pt Georgia), the dlus get smaller:

**Segoe UI 9pt:**

[image]

**Note**: You'll notice that *resolution* (i.e. dpi) has no impact on the discussion.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395195/wpf-how-to-specify-units-in-dialog-units

Comment: @Bas As if my linking to it wasn't a giveaway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF: How to specify units in Dialog Units?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395195/wpf-how-to-specify-units-in-dialog-units)

Comment: "Windows UX Guidelines" link is now dead. Could you update it?

Answer (score 2):

You could try creating a `Converter` which returns the value multiplied by whatever your DLU is

For example, I created a `MathConverter` (code is [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/the-math-converter/)) which would let you specify something like

```
<Button Height="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Settings.VerticalDLU,
            Converter={StaticResource MathConverter},
            ConverterParameter=@VALUE*14}"

        Width="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Settings.HorizontalDLU,
            Converter={StaticResource MathConverter},
            ConverterParameter=@VALUE*50}" />
```

To make it easier to write and read, you can create a class that inherits from Binding and setup a default binding properties so all you have to do is

```
<Button Height="{local:MyVDluBinding Source=14}"
        Width="{local:MyHDluBinding Source=50}" />
```

I've never tried overwriting a binding with defaults for `Converter` and `ConverterParameter`, but I have overwritten a binding for validation purposes so I believe it's possible.

The `ValidationBinding` I created could be used like `Text="{local:ValidationBinding MyProperty}"` and automatically set `ValidatesOnDataError=True, ValidatesOnException=True, UpdateSourceTarget=PropertyChanged` in the bindings.

Comment: Why has Ian not accept this answer?  It looks reasonable.  I was going to suggest subclassing and add new DependencyProperties.  You solution looks cleaner.  Also, attached properties might also work.