# WinForms: How to cause MouseEnter to fire when the mouse enters a control?

Tags: winforms

i have a `Panel` which contains an arbitrary number of child controls:

[image]

If the mouse enters one of the child controls in the `Panel`:

[image]

Then the `MouseEnter` event of the `Panel` is not fired.

> **Note:** A related problem is that if the mouse moves from the the **panel** to one of the **child controls**, then the Panel's `MouseLeave` event is fired:
>
> [image]
>
> Even though the mouse did not leave the panel.

How can i cause the `MouseEnter` event of a `Panel` to fire if the mouse enters "any" control that is a child on the panel?

Comment: WPF makes this easier with bubbling events, but in WinForms, you're stuck with writing plumbing code.

Comment: I'm wondering what makes people stick to WinForms. I have been using WPF for the past 4 and half years and never touched WinForms again since then. WPF is charming. Winforms sucks.

Comment: @Shimmy The inability in WPF to [layout forms in dlus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147716/how-to-specify-units-in-dialog-units-in-wpf), the inability [to specify dialog units as units](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395195/wpf-how-to-specify-units-in-dialog-units), the requirement that forms be laid out using an XML markup language, and that you cannot not use databinding.

Comment: @IanBoyd you cannot use databinding was the final and best joke. i am still laughing hard!!

Answer (score 4):

Something like:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in panel1.Controls)
            ctrl.MouseEnter += panel1_MouseEnter;
```

Comment: Perhaps you can answer how to have the generic code (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173583/winforms-how-to-attach-event-handler-to-other-controls)  Short version: `control.MouseEnter += panel.MouseEnter` doesn't compile.

Comment: It gets hairy when i have a few dozen panels, and i don't know the *names* of the methods attached to each event. You'd think a computer would be able to tell you such things - rather than having to maintain such a large ball of mud.

Comment: I wrote "panel1_MouseEnter" - meaning the default event handler Visual Studio writes for you. Not "control.MouseEnter += panel.MouseEnter" - which, agreed, doesn's compile.

Comment: One possible solution would be to create a UserControl which takes care of this and use that instead of the standard Panel. "PanelWhichFiresMouseEnterForItsChildren" :-)