# Winforms: How to attach an event handler to additional controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How do i attach the same event handler to additional controls in Winforms/.NET/C#?

---

i ***randomly*** tried perfectly logical code to accomplish what i want, but unfortunately the syntax is not valid in C#:

```
public MainForm()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   FixPanelMouseEnter(pnlActionCenter);
   FixPanelMouseEnter(pnlAdministrativeTools);
   FixPanelMouseEnter(pnlAutoPlay);
   FixPanelMouseEnter(pnlBackupAndRestore);
   //...snip 49 lines...
   FixPanelMouseEnter(pnlWFirewall);
   FixPanelMouseEnter(pnlWLiveLanguageSettings);
   FixPanelMouseEnter(pnlWUpdate);
}

private void FixPanelMouseEnter(Panel panel)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in panel.Controls)
        ctrl.MouseEnter += panel.MouseEnter;
}
```

This *invalid* code causes the ***syntax error***:

> The event 'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEnter' can only appear on the left hand side of a += or -=

In this example i want the Panel's `MouseEnter` event to fire if the mouse enter's any control in the panel.

[How do i attach the same event handler to additional controls in Winforms/.NET/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173583/winforms-how-to-attach-same-event-handler-to-additional-controls)

The code i tried doesn't compile.

### Related Questions

- [WinForms: How to cause MouseEnter to fire when the mouse enters a control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172535/winforms-how-to-cause-mouseenter-to-fire-when-the-mouse-enters-a-control)
- [.NET: How to check if the mouse is in a control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159534/net-how-to-check-if-the-mouse-is-in-a-control)

Comment: @Oded The sensible syntax that i **tried** to use doesn't compile **The event 'MouseEnter' can only appear on the left hand side of a += or -=**. i'll change the question to bold the compile error of the code that doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't compile because you put an event, not a handler on the right side of the `+=`. You need to subscribe to a _method_ not an _event_ (in this case `panel.MouseEnter`).

Comment: @Oded Can something like reflection be used to get the method attached to an event, and attach that method to another event?

Comment: Not a reflection expert, but I doubt it. As far as I know, reflection works on static types, so the dynamic nature of delegate invocation lists is probably not something that can be done. I would ask that as a new question, if I were you :)

Comment: @Oded i'm already three questions in, in trying to solve "quirks" in WinForms and C#. Every thing i try i'm thwarted by .NET. :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I am mostly a web guy, so not really a winforms expert. I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve either. But every question should get you closer to an answer that solves your issue.

Comment: @Oded The problem, two questions back, is that if the mouse enters a control *in* the panel, then panel *itself* it not told that mouse enters. Events do not bubble up in .NET, as they do in other languages.

Comment: @Oded about reflection: had you seen the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129517/c-sharp-how-to-find-if-an-event-is-hooked-up)?

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
ctrl.MouseEnter += panel.MouseEnter;
```

to

```
ctrl.MouseEnter += panel_MouseEnter;
```

Assuming the method `void panel_MouseEnter` already exists in your code.

I think you need to then pass the EventHandler, too:

```
private void FixPanelMouseEnter(Panel panel, EventHandler enterMethod) {
  foreach (Control ctrl in panel.Controls)
    ctrl.MouseEnter += enterMethod;
}
```

and then from your code:

```
FixPanelMouseEnter(pnlActionCenter, pnlActionCenter_MouseEnter);
```

But again, the pnlActionCenter_MouseEnter must already exist.  Make sense?

Comment: That doesn't compile, *"The name 'panel_MouseEnter' does not exist in the current context"*

Comment: @IanBoyd Are your creating these Panels at runtime?  As noted by me and Oded, you have to have the method already written in order to subscribe to it.

Comment: Well i don't know how the person who's calling my helper method **FixPanelMouseEnter** is creating their panels. Strictly speaking all panels are *created* at runtime. But i don't know the name of panels in projects that haven't been written yet.

Comment: Is there a way to get that method at runtime? Would something like reflection be able to help?

Comment: I see what your are doing now.  It's a slippery slope and I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159534/net-how-to-check-if-the-mouse-is-in-a-control/8170035#8170035) is your best bet.  The code from this question's example doesn't even consider controls inside of controls inside your panel-- now you have to keep adding handlers recursively.  As you can see, it's getting uglier and uglier.

Answer (score 1):

If your event handler for `panel.MouseEnter` is called `panel_MouseEnter`, use this code:

```
private void FixPanelMouseEnter(Panel panel)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in panel.Controls)
        ctrl.MouseEnter += panel_MouseEnter;
}
```

Note that the event handler needs to be a *method*, not an *event*.

This method (which could be an anonymous method) need to conform to the [`EventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx) delegate signature - `void EventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)`.

---

Update:

I see now what you are trying to achieve.

Here is one way to get your code to work:

```
private void FixPanelMouseEnter(Panel panel, EventHandler commonHandlerForPanel)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in panel.Controls)
        ctrl.MouseEnter += commonHandlerForPanel;
}
```

Comment: The panels are not all called "panel".

Comment: @IanBoyd - The point here isn't about names, but about the _handler_ method name. You can subscribe `panel2.MouseEnter` to _any_ method that conforms to the delegate signature `void MethodName(object sender, EventArgs e)`.

Comment: Then i would need a way to determine the method name of the *handler*.

Comment: @IanBoyd - Seeing as you would _have_ the name (as the method would be written), I don't quite understand the issue.

Comment: @IanBoyd - Answer updated. You can pass in a delegate to your method. The events can subscribe to this delegate.

Comment: Reddog has a worthwhile comment (http://stackoverflow.com/q/8174203/12597) There may multiple methods attached to the event handler. And at the very least i need to pass an `IEnumerable<EventHandler>` list of **EventHandlers**.

Comment: Since delegates can contain multiple "instances" in invocation lists, that might not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cause the event to fire.
Best thing you can do is attach the same handler to all the events by using something like:

```
ctrl.MouseEnter += panel1_MouseEnter;
```

inside your loop, where panel1_MouseEnter is the event handler.
It's possible even that you want to do this recursively in case you have nested panels for example.

Comment: That's a good point, that `.Controls` collection might not contain all child `Controls`. That will require further investigation once i have a functioning method.