# WinForms/.NET: How to get the event handler attached to an event?

Tags: .net, winforms, reflection, delegates

How can i get the event handler attached to an event?

pseudocode, for example's sake:

```
public static EventHandler GetChangeUICuesEventHandler(Control SomeControl)
{
   EventHandler changeUICuesEventHandler = SomeControl.ChangeUICues;
   return changeUICuesEventHandler
}
```

Sample usage (pseudo-code):

```
Control control = GetControlByName(Console.ReadLine());
button1.ChangeUICues += GetChangeUICuesEventHandler(control);
```

Comment: In your pseudocode method at the start, I would expect there could be multiple event handlers attached to the event, so you'll need to return an IEnumerable<EventHandler> if you can get this to work.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that. Usually I let each control implement an interface where the event is defined. If that is not possible I usually chain events.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine if an event is already subscribed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697247/how-to-determine-if-an-event-is-already-subscribed)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293007/is-it-possible-to-steal-an-event-handler-from-one-control-and-give-it-to-anoth/293031#293031

Answer (score 1):

I offer up the following as an alternative path rather than a direct answer... So here goes...

Can you approach this a little differently perhaps by ensuring that your control with the event handler already attached, in this case the parameter `someControl`, instead implements an interface that defines the attached handler. For example:

```
public interface ChangUICuesHandler
{
    void OnChangeUICues(object sender, EventArgs e);
}
```

Then you could use it like so:

```
Control control = GetControlByName(Console.ReadLine());
if (!(control is ChangeUICuesHandler))
{
    throw new Exception("Input Control does not implement the interface");
}
var handlerControl = control as ChangeUICuesHandler;
button.ChangeUICues += handler.OnChangeUICues;
```